# One click web deployment package for an asp.net website (not a web application)

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, web-deployment

I am looking for a way to create a web deployment package for an asp.net website through Visual Studio 2010. I have been looking around for a while but found all for an web application and not many for a deploying a web site. I would really appreciate if you can provide me with a resource or a guidance on this.

Comment: Yet another reason to not use Web Site "projects".

Comment: So John, do you think there is no way to do it? I would really appreciate if you can also state a reason on why are you so against using a website "project". This would help me in making a better decision if I have to in future. I appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I could not add comment, so, I would pretend, that this is an answer.
The only major problem of web site project against web application project is the fact, that it does not support web.config transformation out of the box and there is no way to package it from VS also.
However, you could still use msdeploy to deliver you website folder to your target server:
%msdeploy% -verb:sync  -source:contentPath="path\to\your\website\folder" -dest:contentPath="IIS website name",computerName="handler\on\target\computer",username="username",password=password,authType="Basic"